# Invert pixel color between a contour and the extended contour

Tags: python, opencv, graphics

In am image, I am finding contours and then picking one contour at a time and then modifying each one of them. I need to invert colors of the region only between those two contour lines.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
%matplotlib inline
im = cv2.imread('bigO.jpg')
im = np.invert(im)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
# plt.imshow(imgray)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Get any one contour
cnt = contours[1]

#Extend the contour
def rand_xy(mu, sigma):
    return np.random.normal(mu, sigma), np.random.normal(mu, sigma)
cnt_new = np.asarray([point + rand_xy(mu = 5., sigma = 0.5) for point in cnt], dtype=np.int32)

#DRAW CONTOURS
cv2.drawContours(im, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, cnt_new, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(im)

#Here I need to invert the color of images between the contours.
```

[image]

[image]

Expected output:

The expected is the entire image with the pixels inverted between the two contours.

Comment: If your image is binary (uint8) and you want to invert it why not just applying a `cv2.bitwise_not(im)` ?

Comment: The OP is to invert colors only between two contours and not the entire image. Added one more image to make the question more clear

Comment: 1. Make a mask: mark the space between the contours on a new blank image so that it's black between the contours and white otherwise (probably easier to draw the opposite and then invert the mask). 2. Use that new mask to choose where to invert colors by passing it as the `mask` parameter in `cv2.bitwise_not(img, mask=...)`. This will flip the colors of the pixels in `img` only where they are white (non-zero) in your mask.

Answer (score 0):

Binarize your image and invert it by applying a bitwise not operator

```
im = np.clip(im,0,255).astype(np.uint8)
im = cv2.bitwise_not(im)
```

or:

```
_, im = cv2.threshold(im.astype(np.uint8),0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Comment: The OP is to invert colors only between two contours and not the entire image. I added one more image to make it clear

Comment: Is the last image the expected output ?

Comment: If I well understood you wand to distinguish the points of the two contours ?
why not simply do :
cv2.drawContours(im, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, cnt_new, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
rather than:
cv2.drawContours(im, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.drawContours(im, cnt_new, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

Comment: The expected is the entire image with the pixels inverted between the two contours.